# Not able to get all the logs in application insights even after disabling sampling

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I am generating  logs for my client application where there is very limited internet connectivity. I am storing the offline logs and generating it to application insights once the user is back online. The problem I am facing is out of all the logs only request logs are coming rest are getting discarded. This is happening because of sampling even though I have already disabled the sampling from Startup.cs. Here is my code:

```
var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
    aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
```

Any Suggestions how to completely remove the sampling so that I can have all the logs in application insight.

Comment: Could you please refer this MS DOC once https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#configuring-fixed-rate-sampling-for-aspnet-core-applications

Comment: *This is happening because of sampling* -> How are you so sure sampling is the issue?

Comment: *I am storing the offline logs and generating it to application insights once the user is back online.* -> How? using the AI server channel or a custom solution?

Comment: @PeterBons- By running this query, union requests,dependencies,pageViews,browserTimings,exceptions,traces
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| summarize RetainedPercentage = 100/avg(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h), itemType    I found that the retained percentage  were as low as 25.

Answer (score 0):

- Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#control-logging-level) to see different log levels. if you have latest version of sdk than ILogger Can capture without required action.
- It will capture log level.
  Here is the configuration of logging level.

```
    .ConfigureLogging(
                builder =>
                {                
                    builder.AddApplicationInsights("ikey");
      builder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Information); // this will capture Info level traces and above.
                }
```

- For complete information check this SO thread.